# How to convert Array Object to Object in React native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, object, arrayobject

I called API Called and fetch the array like this.

```
0:
2019-07-25: {title: "Sub task for 11"}
__proto__: Object
1: {2019-07-19: {…}}
2: {2019-07-24: {…}}
3: {2019-07-26: {…}}
4: {2019-07-25: {…}}
5: {2019-07-24: {…}}
6: {2019-07-25: {…}}
7: {2019-07-25: {…}}
```

I want convert above object array to the object. Like below..

```
     "2019-07-25": {title: "Sub task for 11"},
     "2019-07-19": {title: "Sub task for 12"},
     "2019-07-24": {title: "Sub task for 13"},
     "2019-07-26": {title: "Sub task for 14"}
```

I tried but I can not convert like this. Please anyone know how to convert this help me. Thank you

Comment: please post the code also you have tried so far

Comment: that's a javascript issue

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this:

```js
const input = [
  { "2019-07-25": { title: "Sub task for 11" } },
  { "2019-07-19": { title: "Sub task for 12" } },
  { "2019-07-24": { title: "Sub task for 13" } }
];

const output = Object.assign({}, ...input)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Hello and if it comes from an iteration how could I iterate all? @adiga

Comment: @DanyMartinez_ what you mean by *comes from an iteration*? Can you add some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to achieve this

```js
var res = [
  { "2019-07-25": { title: "Sub task for 11" } },
  { "2019-07-19": { title: "Sub task for 12" } },
  { "2019-07-24": { title: "Sub task for 13" } }
].reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, ...b }))
     
console.log(res)
```